# Recovering deleted messages and data on a mobile phone

Tags: android, security, mobile, operating-system, symbian

I want to design a mobile application/tool for recovering deleted messages/pictures/files from the phone. I have the choice to do that using Android or Symbian. what do you think is more easier provided that I have to use some operating system concepts to solve the problem and recover deleted messages. Also what are the concepts that I can use for recovery ?

Comment: We're going to need more information/requirements. Do you plan on replacing the whole default messaging application on the handset just so it "hides" messages instead of deleting them? Do you plan on reading "gost" information off of unalocated persistent memory like one would on a desktop hard drive? Do you plan on having a remote messaging service that "hides" messages instead of deleting them?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobil platforms lock developers into a very small padded room.  I don't think level of access will be possible unless the device is jail broken.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can have access to deleted messages in Symbian (unless you use some older pre 3rd edition phone model). And undeleting files and pictures from phone is also impossible.

Answer (score -3):

Android and Symbian have access to this information. Gone are the days of locked down J2me development. :)